# FME: Join attributes in text file with attributes in shapefile

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile with points and different attributes - one attribute `MyID`. I also have a plain text file with several attributes - each in a separated column:

```
MyID MyValue
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 :    :
```

I would like to use FME to append my attributes in the text file using the attribute key/value `MyID`.

**Is this possible, and in that case how?**

Comment: GIS-Jonathan got the post in first... Mapperz was 6mins behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Feature Merger** transformer will allow you to Join by attributes

[image]
Using FME Desktop 2012 SP2 here

http://docs.safe.com/fme/pdf/FMEReadersWriters.pdf

Search 'Feature Merger'

A good blog post 'Joiner vs Feature Merger' by Mark Ireland

http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist79/

Comment: For very large datasets (I tested 4+ million features) the Joiner is **much** faster (i.e. 1hr 45 versus 3hrs). But generally speaking the FeatureMerger is easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily in a number of ways, but the best way would be to use the `FeatureMerger` Transformer.

The `Requestor` will be the shapefile, the `Supplier` will be the text file. If you leave the settings on their defaults that should be fine for you. This will give you parameters that look like this:

[image]

Note: The first few times you run it be sure to connect visualisers/inspectors to _all_output ports for the FeatureMerger. This way you'll be able to see what does/doesn't match.

The output of the "complete" port will have the merged features in the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at inlinequerier ,it deserves your attention for the future when you need to chain multiple featuremergers , it creates indexes in a smarter way and speedsup your translations. Inlinequerier ... have a look.

Jorge Vidinha